# OpenGL: Pause screen contents for some given time

Tags: opengl

I'm new to Open GL (and I'm using the old Open GL API) and I'm trying to implement step 3 as given below:

```
1. Draw something
2. Draw some more things.
3. Don't draw anything NEW for some time t. But keep displaying whatever has been drawn so far.
4. Time t has elapsed, move on to drawing new things.
```

`sleep()` and other similar functions obviously don't work, because it doesn't draw *any* thing during the sleep time, so you just get a blank screen for time t.

How do I go about doing this?

Comment: Try doing `glFlush` before sleeping.

Comment: Didn't work.. Now it just draws everything after the sleep duration in one go

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is that you draw to the front buffer. Say if you want to draw A first, then wait for a few seconds, then draw B:

1. Draw A.
2. SwapBuffers
3. Sleep.
4. glDrawBuffer(GL_FRONT)
5. Draw B.
6. glFlush()
7. glDrawBuffer(GL_BACK)

Drawing to the front buffer is generally not recommended anymore these days, and not even supported in some variations of OpenGL (e.g. OpenGL ES).

The more standard option is that you draw your whole scene again when you want to update it with more content:

1. Draw A.
2. SwapBuffers
3. Sleep.
4. Draw A
5. Draw B.
6. SwapBuffers

If drawing A is very expensive, you can consider approaches where it gets rendered to an offscreen framebuffer (FBO), and then copied to the default framebuffer when it's needed:

1. Bind FBO.
2. Draw A.
3. Unbind FBO.
4. Copy FBO rendering -> default FB.
5. SwapBuffers
6. Sleep.
7. Copy FBO rendering -> default FB.
8. Draw B.
9. SwapBuffers

Comment: Can you tell me how to "Copy FBO rendering -> default FB" ? What is the API-way to do the copying?

Comment: With GL 3.x or later, `glBlitFramebuffer()` will to the copy very directly. Otherwise you can draw a screen size quad with a simple pair of shaders.